# how can I search string with double single quotes (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `varchar` field `LOCATIONCITY` and there is a value

```
St. John''s
```

I want to search it like following

```
select * from city where locationcity='St. John''s'
```

Since it's a default behavior of sql server that double single quotes are converted to single double qoites

How can I search for 'St. John''s'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two single quotes, each one of which should be escaped by doubling it, so:

```
select * from city where locationcity='St. John''''s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(100)='St. John''s'
set @Name=REPLACE(@Name,'''','''')
select @Name
```